# Why data isn't updating after sorting in React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React Hooks. I'm trying to sort table inside React Hook, but after click my content doesn't update. Why is that?

This is my hook:

```
const Main = ({ dataProps }) => {
const [data, setData] = useState(dataProps);
const sortById = (field) => {
        let sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
            if(a[field] < b[field]) { return -1; }
            if(a[field] > b[field]) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        });
        setData(sortedData);
};
return (
        <table>
            <thead>    
                <tr>
                    <th>iD <div className="arrows"><div onClick={() => sortById("id")} className="arrow-up"/></th>
                    <th>First name <div className="arrows"><div onClick={() => sortById("firstName")} className="arrow-up"/></div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {data.map((user) => {
                return <tr key={user.id}>
                    <td className="number">{user.id}</td>
                    <td className="firstname">{user.firstName}</td>
                </tr>
            })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortById` sorts the `data` array. But it does not trigger the component to rerender. The `field` here is obviously a state:

```
 const [data, setData] = useState(dataProps);      
 const [field, setField] = useState(null);

 const sorted = useMemo(() => {
   if(!field) return data;
   return data.slice().sort((a, b) => a[field].localeCompare(b[field]));
 }, [ data, field]);

 return <div>
   <a onClick={() => setField("firstName")}> Sort by Name</a>
   {sorted.map(/*...*/)}
</div>;
```

Answer (score 2):

problem is sort return same array which won't cause re-render. if you slice before sorting it will fix issue.

```
const sortById = (field) => {
        let sortedData = data.slice().sort((a, b) => {
            if(a[field] < b[field]) { return -1; }
            if(a[field] > b[field]) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        });
        setData(sortedData);
};
```

BTW more efficient way of doing is mentioned by @jonas-wilms

Comment: This saved me so much time . Thanks !!